# Is there any possible way to use built-in await without async in Node.js 7.6+?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I'm a Node.js programmer. Before Node.js 7.6 released, I used the module '[asyncawait](https://github.com/yortus/asyncawait)' to let my code in async-await style. The coding style is like below:

```
var async = require('asyncawait/async');
var await = require('asyncawait/await');

var getData = async(function(finder){
    return await(db.collection.findOne(finder));
});

var f = function(finder){
    return await(getData(finder));
};

try{
    let result = f({id: 1});
}catch(err){
}
```

After Node.js 7.6 released, the async-await function is officially built-in. But the async and await functions(or call them keywords?) seemingly have to be paired in a function. If I change my code to,

```
var getData = async function(finder){
    return await db.collection.findOne(finder);
}

var f = function(finder){
    return await getData(finder);
};

try{
    let result = f({id: 1});
}catch(err){
}
```

The 'await' keyword in 'f' function cannot be recognized. Unless I change the code to,

```
var getData = async function(finder){
    return await db.collection.findOne(finder);
}

var f = async function(finder){
    return await getData(finder);
};

try{
    let result = await f({id: 1});
}catch(err){
}
```

The code will be tedious. Is there any possible way to use built-in await without async in a function?

Comment: thats what promises are for. to essentially turn await into callbacks and async into promises so you can easily switch between syncronous and asyncronous code.

Comment: Also, see [Understand promises before you start using async/await](https://medium.com/@bluepnume/learn-about-promises-before-you-start-using-async-await-eb148164a9c8)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Await can only be used inside async functions.

> The await expression causes async function execution to pause, to wait
>   for the Promise's resolution, and to resume the async function
>   execution when the value is resolved. It then returns the resolved
>   value. If the value is not a Promise, it's converted to a resolved
>   Promise.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await