# Async Await Promise <Pending>

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I know this question been asked for many times but as I'm still very new i dont quite understand the answers on previous places.

```
const publicIp = require('public-ip');

// getting ip address
async function GetIpAddress() {
var a = await publicIp.v4();
return await a;
// it will return my public ip as string
}
```

however ,as its non blocking i understand if i do something like this as below

```
var a = GetIpAddress();
console.log(a);
```

it will probably go promise pending. so what i did was

```
async function hi(){
var a = await GetIpAddress();
console.log(a);
}

hi();
```

But here's my question. How do i return it back to my variables without making another function to cover it up? please see code below

```
var zmq = require('zmq'),
    requester = zmq.socket('req'),
    publicIp = require('public-ip');

const PORT = "3222";
var IP = GetIpAddress();
console.log(`${IP}:${PORT}`);
// IP will return promise pending?? how i do fix this without making another
// function?


requester.connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:5433');

requester.on('message', function (msg) {
    // arr = str.split(",");
    console.log(msg.toString());

});

requester.send(
    `${IP}:${PORT}`
);


async function GetIpAddress() {
    var a = await publicIp.v4();
    return a
}
```

As the full code above shown.. var IP will definitely be promise pending as it will take time. therefore how do it get the function return value without making another function?

EDIT: please understand the duplication is entirely not what i want.. I understand that my knowlege on callbacks , promises and async await wasnt strong but from a guy who comes from synchronous language such as Python itself . I'm very curious onto how do i take variable out. as what i research and saw are mostly

promises within promises or callbacks within callbacks.

what i want is if i can rereplicate what was shown as per below ( python )

```
def f(x):
    return x+1

var1 = 5
var1 = f(var1)
# var1 is now 6
```

which is bringing callbacks / promises / async await variable out of its own function rather than

```
var IP = GetIpAddress().then((IP) => {
    requester.connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:5433');
    console.log('Worker connected to port 5433');

    requester.on('message', function (msg) {
        // arr = str.split(",");
        console.log(msg.toString());

    });

    requester.send(
    `${IP}:${PORT}`
    );
    console.log(`${IP}:${PORT}`);
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any possible way to use built-in await without async in Node.js 7.6+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43066000/is-there-any-possible-way-to-use-built-in-await-without-async-in-node-js-7-6)

Comment: Also, see [Understand promises before you start using async/await](https://medium.com/@bluepnume/learn-about-promises-before-you-start-using-async-await-eb148164a9c8)

Comment: As a guy who come's from python background , What i'm curious of is to bring the value out of promise grasphold and put it back outside of those functions.

what i see mostly are still functions within functions. what i want is how do i bring variable out of functions. hence its not a duplicate

Comment: the links is dead

Comment: Simply put, you can't get the value of asynchronous functions "outside" these functions. Refer to the duplicate, the documentation it cites, and the Medium article for further information.

Comment: thank you boaz , both you and anima below have answered what i truly been questioning about ..

Comment: Please upvote the answers/comments that helped you so other people can find them back more easily.

Comment: unfortunately , my reps arent high enough. so it will not be display .. boaz pls help on this :) Thank you guys..for finding me the answer to this

Comment: You are very welcome. Asynchronous execution in JS can be very confusing at first, especially since it's been continuously changing the past few years. As the Medium article suggests (link appears to be working), start from understanding promises and then work your way to the async/await syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
var IP = GetIpAddress();
console.log(`${IP}:${PORT}`);
```

to:

```
GetIpAddress().then((IP) => {
    console.log(`${IP}:${PORT}`);
  }
);
```

You can read [6 Reasons Why JavaScript’s Async/Await Blows Promises Away (Tutorial)](https://hackernoon.com/6-reasons-why-javascripts-async-await-blows-promises-away-tutorial-c7ec10518dd9#f3f0)

Update:

Option 1 put everything in the `then`:

```
GetIpAddress().then((IP) => {
    requester.connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:5433');
    console.log('Worker connected to port 5433');

    requester.on('message', function (msg) {
        // arr = str.split(",");
        console.log(msg.toString());

    });

    requester.send(
    `${IP}:${PORT}`
    );
    console.log(`${IP}:${PORT}`);
});
```

Option 2 is to wrap everything in an `async` function:

```
async function hi(){
var a = await GetIpAddress();
console.log(a);
}

hi();
```

Option 2 is the one I would opt for as it provides a cleaner way of writing things.

Comment: but wouldnt it be still undefined as you go down the code?

Comment: sadly this .then() doesnt work. console.log still surpass the function first

Comment: Try again with the updated code? I left out catching the result.

Comment: hi anima , yes its working now.. but how do i pass it to the .send? I'm sorry im asking alot but this is really confusing for me

Comment: Either put everything in the `then` part or wrap the whole thing in an `async` function then call that function in the main thread.

Comment: You are welcome. I've updated my answer to reflect your update so it's easier for other people who are reading this.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add await before the method call. the main method also need to async.

var IP = await GetIpAddress();

try to use

```
new promise(function (accept, reject){   // if Ip found
accept("ipaddress")   //else reject("error log")  
 }).then(function(response){ // this is accept , print IPaddress
 }).catch(function(err){ // this is reject. } );
```